# SQLite reverse LIKE wildcard in database

Tags: sqlite

Take this table.

```
 id  |  sentence
 -------------------
 2   |  I % cake.
 3   |  My name is %
```

You will notice the wildcards are actually in the fields within the database.

With MySQL you can do this :

SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE sentence LIKE 'My name is John';

In this example this would return  3.

So it's like a regular LIKE but in reverse.

My question is can this be done any way in SQLite, because when I try it I get no results. Is there a way to implement it perhaps if not ?

EDIT: Sorry was getting my LIKE & MATCH mixed up. Corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sqlite doesn't support a so-called "reverse LIKE" operator (nor does MySQL, for that matter), but it does support what we might call a "reverse reverse LIKE" operator.  Try this:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE 'My name is John' LIKE sentence;
```

Comment: This is what I needed. I feel a bit silly as I had forgotten to switch them around, now it seems obvious. I had learnt this on a PHP + MYSQL project, but failed to spot my error. Thanks.